# Macro expansion in \write

Tags: shell-escape, write

I want to use a macro in `\write18`, but this causes the space after it to be ignored. The following example prints `foobar` to `test.txt`, whereas I want it to print `foo bar`:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\newcommand*{\foo}{foo}
\begin{document}
\write18{echo \foo bar > test.txt}
\end{document}
```

I tried `{\foo}`, `\foo{}`, and `\foo\` instead of just `\foo`, but these all print the braces and slashes to the file, which is not what I want. How can I expand the macro without introducing extra characters, and without removing the space?

The example above is of course simplified. In my real scenario, I am not able to modify the `\foo` command, though I could define a wrapper.

Comment: `\foo\space bar` maybe?

Comment: Yep, `\space` is what I needed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want `\space` instead of `\`  or instead of the braces. Braces are unexpandable tokens which means they're not removed in `\write18`. `\`  is an unexpandable primitive which again means it is not removed (or rather: expanded) in `\write18`. `\space` on the other hand is an expandable macro which expands to a space.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\def\foo{foo}
\edef\test{\foo\ bar}
\show\test

\edef\test{\foo{} bar}
\show\test

\edef\test{\foo\space bar}
\show\test

\end{document}
```

The log entry:

```
> \test=macro:
->foo\ bar.
l.7 \show\test

> \test=macro:
->foo{} bar.
l.10 \show\test

> \test=macro:
->foo bar.
l.13 \show\test
```