# How to get online content using url in LaTeX document?

Tags: hyperref, compiling, document-classes

I want to make a Q&A document where each question is the question posted in [cs.stackexchange.com](https://cs.stackexchange.com/). And the document contains the accepted answer of that site for corresponding question. When I recompile the source code I want to get latest accepted answer.

Is it possible in LaTeX or combining another programming language with LaTeX?

Comment: The getmap package (https://ctan.org/pkg/getmap) retrieves online maps. You could check its code.

Comment: Very flexible and powerful is mixing `LaTeX `with `R` using `Sweave`

Comment: You might even use LuaLaTeX for networking.

Comment: Search for `Sweave Tutorial`. What comes up should satsify all your information and starting needs.

Comment: You could write a script/program to download a question and answer, and generate LaTeX code, in any language you prefer (either download the regular page or use the API with https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/answers-on-questions and such). In your document you can use something like https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/252540 to call the script with a question id and then `\input` the generated code.